# Firebase, how can I login to google service account?

Tags: firebase

To use Firebase, I was stacked to do `firebase int` Error said as follows.

> Error: HTTP Error: 403, Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the firebase.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

Answer (score 2):

Use `firebase login --no-localhost`.